# How to reset the homepage

Tags: magento

I was working on homepage and I altered something to change the feature. But the homepage from then not showing anything. even the categories. showing "woop our bad". I new to this. Please tell me how to set to previous. I tried the reset button. but didn't workout. reset to previous few hours before. Please suggest. I have submit this project in two days. Please...... :(

Comment: When using Magento's WYSIWYG (or any CMS WYSIWYG for that matter), it's a good practice to copy/paste the content into a proper text editor, make your changes there and paste it back into the editor. This way you can always use undo in the text editor to save the history.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change homepage:

```
System > Configuration > Web > CMS Home Page
```

Also have a look to other configuration there. It should be nearly the same as here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-to-change-the-home-page

Comment: I did all the above stuffs before posting. I made some change into homepage. I think I deleted it. How to retrieve that one.

Comment: If you deleted it it will be no way to restore.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset homepage by only updating cms_page table for "**Home page**" field content from magento sample data.

There is no other way provided in magento admin section.